# PhoneGap check dependency failed when run in ios emulator

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova

I have downloaded `ios-sim` through npm to the project. Also I have lastest Cordova installed.

When I try to run my example program (Created through `phonegap create 1example`) with the following command line:

```
phonegap run ios
```

I received the following error message (I will include the whole log, why not)

```
The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

More details:

```
2014-03-04 13:57:21.294 ios-sim[35061:507] 
stderrPath:/Users/oasis_weng/
Desktop/repos/1example/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-03-04 13:57:21.296 ios-sim[35061:507] stdoutPath: 
/Users/oasis_weng/Desktop/repos/2BPEase/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator 
session timed out." UserInfo=0x7ff18b410a40 
{NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}
```

This is the log( error is above):

```
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
[phonegap] successfully compiled iOS app
soudaodieleba:2BPEase oasis_weng$ phonegap run ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
[phonegap] successfully compiled iOS app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
[error] An error occurred while emulating/deploying the ios project. ** BUILD FAILED **
```

I did not modify any files in this project. How should I solve this problem?

More Info:
When I run `phonegap build ios`, it compiles successfully.

Comment: I'm upgrading to Cordova 3.4 right now and see a problem like yours when running on an iOS 6.1 simulator. It works for iOS 7.1

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem?